# Spring service not injected in web servlet

Tags: spring, servlets, dependency-injection

I am using Spring DI and trying to inject a Spring service  in my servlet. However, it isn't injected and stays `null`, causing `NullPointerException`.

My servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Register"}, displayName = "RegisterServlet")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("registerServlet")
    public void setCustomerService(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ...
        customerService.save(customer); // Fail, because service is null.
        // ...
    }

}
```

My spring-controller.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="registerServlet" class="com.fishingstore.controller.RegisterServlet">
        <property name="customerService" ref="customerService"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My Customer DAO class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    // ...
}
```

My Customer service class:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customerService")
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    // ...
}
```

My spring-service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="customerService" class="com.fishingstore.service.implementation.CustomerServiceImpl">
        <property name="customerDAO" ref="customerDAO"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You are using `registerServlet` qualifier to inject `CustomerService` bean in your servlet. Is that correct, I suspect.

Comment: I'm inject bean in my servlet without @Qualifier, it's doesn't work

Comment: Do not ask why you got a `NullPointerException`. [Every Java developer knows the answer to that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Instead ask why a given variable is `null`. I reduced irrelevant code from the question to make it better focused.

Comment: BalusC, Thanks, you are right, I incorrectly formulated my question. I will be more attentive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Servlets` are not managed by `Spring` Container. So apparently any `@Autowired` annotations in that class will not be processed.

Spring provides two static methods in the class [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html)
which can be used in the the servlet classes to enable `Autowiring` feature.

1. [processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(Object target)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html#processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext-java.lang.Object-)
2. [processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(Object target,
                                                        ServletContext servletContext)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html#processInjectionBasedOnServletContext-java.lang.Object-javax.servlet.ServletContext-)

An example using the first method is [here](http://www.javavillage.in/spring-ioc-on-servlets.php) and for the second method is [here](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2012/02/injecting-spring-beans-into-java-servlets/)

The idea behind the two approaches is to override the `Servlet's` `init` method and enable the autowiring of beans.

For example -

```
@Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

    }
```

Make sure you autowire the beans correctly as pointed out in  **@Reimeus** answer.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the `CustomerService` qualifier to match the bean id or better remove `@Qualifier` entirely

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customerService")
public void setCustomerService(CustomerService customerService) {
```

Do the same for `customerDAO`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customerDAO")
private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
```